# Longest common prefix in APL?

Tags: apl

What's the idiomatic way to implement longest common prefix in APL? In Aaron Hsu's thesis, footer page number 76, it is said:

> the idiom `+.=` computes the length of the common prefix shared by two paths

This works in the case we are interested in the paper, since we are guaranteed that two paths, once they stop matching, will not have any more matches. However, *this assumption does not hold in general*.  By way of examples:

```
(5⍴1) +.=(1 1 2 2 1) ⍝ expected answer 2. LCP is (1 1)
3
```

We get the answer as `3` since there is a match `1` at index `5`!

```
(5⍴1)+.=(6⍴2) ⍝ expected answer: 0. NOT length error
LENGTH ERROR
```

The other problem is that the above definition only works if the two arrays have the same shape.

These are unsatisfying to me, so:

Q1. How do I implement longest common prefix for 1D arrays in APL that:

- is correct even when the arrays have repeated elements *after* the initial common prefix.
- Robustly works for arrays of differing shapes.

---

In trying to write down the condition under which the idiom `a+.= b` correctly computes LCP, I arrived at:

> if `len_common_prefix(a, b) = l`, then for all `i > l, i < len(a), i < len(b), a[i] != b[i]`.

Trying to APL-ify this condition led me to:

> if `len_common_prefix(a, b) = l`, then `+/l↓a=b` is `0`.

Q2. The above definition is slightly incorrect since for `=` to work, we need length of `a` and `b` to be equal. How would one write this condition correctly in APL, such that it robustly works for `a` and `b` of differing lengths?

---

I found code on  [codegolf.stackexchange for longest common prefix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62752/longest-common-prefix-of-2-strings/62855#62855) whose proposed solution has the same problem:

```
      {⊃↓K/⍨=⌿K←↑⍵} (5 ⍴ 1) (1 1 1 0 1) ⍝ expected: (1 1 1)
1 1 1 1
```

Clearly, this has the same problem of *assuming that the strings are completely mismatched after the common prefix*, so this answer is incorrect.

---

I attempted a search on [APLCart](https://aplcart.info/) which lists:

```
Cv{⊃⌽⊃(⊢⌈(⌈\(⍵=⊣)+0,¯1↓⊢))/(⌽⍺),⊂0⊣¨⍵}Dv    Length of longest common substring
```

I was hoping to modify it to build a longest common prefix. On trying it out:

```
      'aaaaa' {⊃⌽⊃(⊢⌈(⌈\(⍵=⊣)+0,¯1↓⊢))/(⌽⍺),⊂0⊣¨⍵}'aaaba'
4
```

Unfortunately, this too suffers from the same bug. What it finds is the longest common *subsequence*, not the longest common *substring*.

---

To reiterate, my questions are:

- Q1. How do I implement longest common prefix for 1D arrays in APL that works correctly for strings of different lengths?
- Q2. How do I write down the condition:

> if `len_common_prefix(a, b) = l`, then for all `i > l, i < len(a), i < len(b), a[i] != b[i]`.

in APL fashion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## A1

A short version fit for APLcart would be `{+/∧\⊃=/⍺⍵↑¨⍨⌊/≢¨⍺⍵}`.

An expanded version:

```
{
  len_left  ← ≢ ⍺   ⍝ length of left argument
  len_right ← ≢ ⍵   ⍝ length of right argument

  le_min ← ⌊/ len_left len_right   ⍝ shortest argument's length

  cut_left  ← len_min ↑ ⍺   ⍝ shortened left argument
  cut_right ← len_min ↑ ⍵   ⍝ shortened right argument

  eq_all  ← cut_left = cut_right   ⍝ elements that are equal
  eq_lead ← ∧\ eq_all              ⍝ leading elements that are equal (turn all 1s off after first 0)
  +/ eq_lead                       ⍝ count common prefix
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///Pyc1Lz45Pzc3Py@@oCg1LbNC4VHbBIVqbf1HHctjHnU12@o/6t31qHfro7aJh1Y86l3xqKdL/1HnIhAbJFzL9ahvKlCHemJSsroCpmEgcYWU1DR1JHUgLj6l//8DAA)

## A2

A simple translation to APL:

> if `l←a len_common_prefix b` then for all `(i>l)∧(i<≢a)∧(i<≢b)`, `a[i]≠b[i]`

However, we could state it with array comprehension which also actually defines `i`:

> if `l←a len_common_prefix b` then for `i←l↓⍳⌊/≢¨a b`, `∧/a[i]≠b[i]`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer :) I am confused by the use of the `DIAERESIS (¨)` operator in the expression for `i`: `i←l↓⍳⌊/≢¨a b`. What function is getting mapped over what? In general, I'm finding expressions involving map hard to read...

Comment: @SiddharthBhat It is essential to know the syntactic class of the symbols. Monadic operators take as their operand the function phrase to their immediate left. In this case, `¨` has `≢` to its left. Reading further we have `/` which is not a dyadic operator, and so doesn't affect `≢`. It is then safe to conclude that `¨` only takes `≢` as operand.

Answer (score 0):

Q1. [`+/∧\=⌿↑a b`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBImP2iaoF5cUZealq3MlQTn5eempRepc2vqPOpbH2D7q2f@obWKiQhIA)

`↑` is [mix](http://help.dyalog.com/17.0/Content/Language/Primitive%20Functions/Mix.htm). it arranges the two strings (left-aligned) in a 2-row matrix, padding the shorter one with spaces

`=⌿` compares the two chars in each column. it produces a boolean vector (of 0s and 1s)

`∧\` is "and-scan". it preserves the leading sequence of 1s and turns all other 1s to 0s

`+/` sum

note that if the longer string can have trailing spaces, this might give wrong results

Q2. you could use [take](http://help.dyalog.com/17.0/Content/Language/Primitive%20Functions/Take.htm) (`n↑`) and [drop](http://help.dyalog.com/17.0/Content/Language/Primitive%20Functions/Drop.htm) (`n↓`) to cut out the relevant slice of the boolean vector from Q1